# Apache Beam on Cloud Dataflow - Failed to query Cadvisor

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a cloud dataflow that is reading from a Pub/Sub and pushing data out to BQ. Recently the dataflow is reporting the error below and not writing any data to BQ.

```
{
 insertId:  "3878608796276796502:822931:0:1075"  
 jsonPayload: {
  line:  "work_service_client.cc:490"   
  message:  "gcpnoelevationcall-01211413-b90e-harness-n1wd Failed to query CAdvisor at URL=<IPAddress>:<PORT>/api/v2.0/stats?count=1, error: INTERNAL: Couldn't connect to server"   
  thread:  "231"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "3878608796276796502"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "gcpnoelevationcall-01211413-b90e-harness-n1wd"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_type:  "instance"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id:  "2018-01-21_14_13_45"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name:  "gcpnoelevationcall"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region:  "global"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/poc/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fshuffler"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-21T22:41:40.053806623Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "2018-01-21_14_13_45"    
   job_name:  "gcpnoelevationcall"    
   project_id:  "poc"    
   region:  "global"    
   step_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2018-01-21T22:41:39.524005Z"  
}
```

Any ideas, on how could I help this? Has anyone faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this just happened once it could be attributed to a transient issue. The process running on the worker node can't reach [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor). Either the cAdvisor container is not running or there is a temporal problem on the worker that can't contact cAdvisor and the job gets stuck.

Comment: I can also see some log saying unable to mount volume. The data flow job status is still running through. Should i expect the job to rectify itself? or it will need to be restarted? The job hasn't started processing data yet.

Comment: Normally these are just transient issues but when they happen the job seems to be stuck and my advice would be to stop it and retry again. Let me know if it works then.

Comment: Yes a restart of the job did seem to work. Thanks :)